# How to chat in Arabic with Microsoft's GODEL?

Tags: python

https://huggingface.co/microsoft/GODEL-v1_1-large-seq2seq

I downloaded Microsoft's GODEL model from the address above.

Using the python code example here, you can get normal output when chatting in English, but you get abnormal output when using Arabic. How do you set up Arabic chat?

example:

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("F:\\code\\py-web\\GODEL-v1_1-large-seq2seq")
model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained("F:\\code\\py-web\\GODEL-v1_1-large-seq2seq")

def generate(instruction, knowledge, dialog):
    if knowledge != '':
        knowledge = '[KNOWLEDGE] ' + knowledge
    dialog = ' EOS '.join(dialog)
    query = f"{instruction} [CONTEXT] {dialog} {knowledge}"
    input_ids = tokenizer(f"{query}", return_tensors="pt").input_ids
    outputs = model.generate(input_ids, max_length=128, min_length=8, top_p=0.9, do_sample=True)
    output = tokenizer.decode(outputs[0], skip_special_tokens=True)
    return output
# Instruction for a chitchat task
instruction = f'أين تقع الجزيرة العربية؟'
# Leave the knowldge empty
knowledge = ''
dialog = []
response = generate(instruction, knowledge, dialog)
print(response)
```